# Do Resources not duplicate when instancing an object?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

Quick explanation, I am making a tower defense game and I am instancing each tower, each tower has an array of resources called Upgrade, this upgrade resource keeps track of cost and level and should be different for each instance I make, but it seems resources are shared between each instance, I also noticed when I update the collision shape for a range increase that is also shared between instances which I found strange.

from what I can tell the script variables are being duplicated thats good but the resources are shared between them, how do I make it so the resources aren't being shared.

here is a video on my yt channel with a visual representation of the issue I am having.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar1iAYbX7_I

code of the upgrade resource:

```
class_name Upgrade extends Resource

@export var Name : String
@export var Inital_Cost : float
@export var Upgrade_Value : float = 10
var Cost : int = 0
var Level : float = 1
@export var Max_Level : int = 30
var Growth_Factor : float = 2
var Slot : Array

func Calculate_Cost() -> void:
    var calculated_cost : float = Inital_Cost * pow(Growth_Factor,Level)
    Cost = calculated_cost
```

Here is the script I use to instance each tower.

```
extends Node

@export var Basic_Tower : PackedScene
@export var Building_Mode : bool = false
var Current_Tower : Node3D
@export var Raycast : RayCast3D

func _process(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Interact"):
        Building_Mode = !Building_Mode
    
    # Check which mode we are in and we either clear the hand or we give a tower
    Check_Mode()
    
    # Upgrade code where you can select the tower and upgrade them
    if not Building_Mode and Input.is_action_just_pressed("Left_Click"):
        if Raycast.is_colliding():
            var Obj = Raycast.get_collider()
            if Obj.is_in_group("Tower"):
                EventSystem.Emit_Event("Set_Upgrade_Target",[Obj])
    
    if Current_Tower == null: return
    # This bit allows to place the tower onto the ground
    var Collision_Point = Raycast.get_collision_point()
    
    if Raycast.is_colliding() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("Left_Click"):
            Current_Tower.global_position = Collision_Point
            Current_Tower.set_process_mode(0)
            Current_Tower = null
    elif Raycast.is_colliding():
            Current_Tower.global_position = Collision_Point

func Check_Mode():
    if Building_Mode and Current_Tower == null and Raycast.is_colliding():
        var Instance = Basic_Tower.instantiate()
        Current_Tower = Instance
        Instance.process_mode = 4
        get_tree().get_root().add_child(Instance)
        
    elif not Raycast.is_colliding() and Current_Tower != null:
        Current_Tower.queue_free()
        Current_Tower = null
    elif not Building_Mode and Current_Tower != null:
        Current_Tower.queue_free()
        Current_Tower = null
```

Comment: Maybe check the [`Local to scene`](https://godotforums.org/assets/files/2023-06-24/1687596733-318992-image.png) option?

Comment: @cak3_lover this solves the collision shape from changing globally but the upgrade resource doesnt seem to be able to be local to the scene, maybe Im doing something wrong, this is a nice temp fix, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a few more google searches this is actually a bug where enabling local to scene does not work in an export array, so the only work around I can do is having these resources top level instead of an array.

Github issue: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/71243